# Apps launched from shell scripts do not run from Unity bar

Tags: 11.04, unity, command-line, oracle

I can run Oracle's SQL Developer 3.0 by clicking on "sqldeveloper.sh" from the file manager and then clicking "Run".
When I add it to the Unity menu (Right-click running icon in menu, click "Keep in Launcher", the new icon doesn't work.

Once I close SQL Developer, I click on the new icon in the Unity bar and it does nothing except flash a few times.

Comment: It's a bug, alas: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/765466

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the desktop and create a new launcher. Then drag this launcher to the unity bar.

I would recommend to move the launcher to another folder before you drag it to the unity bar because you just create a link to that launcher. If you move the launcher to ~/.local/share/applications/ you are also able to find it by typing the name in the unity search.

Answer (score 1):

That worked, partially.  I do get a launcher entry.  However, when I actually run the launcher entry, the running instance of SQL Developer adds an additional icon into the launcher (slightly different image with a green background).

The sqldeveloper.desktop file contents are as follows

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
Comment=Oracle SQL Developer
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=sqldeveloper
Hidden=false
Icon=/usr/share/sqldeveloper/icon.png
Name=Oracle SQL Developer
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

The second icon has no "Keep in Launcher" option if I right click on it.

Any suggestions for getting the launcher to associate the running program with the original launcher icon?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please ask this as a new question by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button on the top right of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get Oracle SQL Developer to work correctly from dash by adding the following line to my `sqldeveloper.desktop` file located in `~/.local/share/applications/`:

```
StartupWMClass=oracle-ide-boot-Launcher
```

This was found by using

```
xprop WM_CLASS
```

and clicking on the opened SQL Developer Window.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, it was also needed adding the JAVA_HOME environment variable. So the sqldeveloper.sh now looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_34
cd "`dirname $0`"/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $* > sqldeveloper.log &
```